# Finding the last variable in __attribute__(section)

Tags: c, linker, cross-compiling, gnu, xilinx

I'm currently working on an embedded system, and in order to meet time constraints I've needed to lock some code in cache. I've placed all the functions I will need to be locked cache into the section MEMORY_CACHEABLE by using the section variable attribute.

Because the board I'm using sets memory attributes for 1 megabyte chunks, I've made MEMORY_CACHEABLE 1MB in size.

When it comes to actually locking the code in cache, I need to determine the high address for the code inside of MEMORY_CACHEABLE, since it does not occupy the entire memory space and I don't want to lock unused memory in cache.

The way I've been doing this is by using a placeholder in MEMORY_CACHEABLE, that is defined in my C code after all of the other function placed in MEMORY_CACHEABLE. Every time I've debugged, I've confirmed that the placeholder has a higher address than the other function. I've been using this value as the high address, but it seems a little hacky.

I know there's no standard way of determining the size of a C function at runtime, but is there a more straightforward way to discover the high address of the code in this specific memory section?

Also, I'm cross-compiling using arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc.

Thanks!

Comment: one simple way to get the code size of a function to acquire the address of the target function and the address of the next function and subtract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a linker script for that. Maybe you are already using one to specify the memory section attributes.

So, just add:

```
MEMORY_CACHEABLE :
{
    BEGIN_MEMORY_CACHEABLE = .;
    *(MEMORY_CACHEABLE)
    END_MEMORY_CACHEABLE = .;
}
```

Then in the C code:

```
extern char BEGIN_MEMORY_CACHEABLE, END_MEMORY_CACHEABLE;
```

And use `&BEGIN_MEMORY_CACHEABLE` as a pointer to the beginning and `&END_MEMORY_CACHEABLE` a pointer to one-past-end of your cacheable memory.

Comment: This works perfectly! I had no idea you could reference those values from the linker script as extern variables.

Thanks!

Comment: @MrMojo: That's because the linker deals with symbol addresses, so these values are just thow other external symbols. That's why you need the address-of `&` operator to access the real value.